# onclick function from jQuery to pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have snippet of code in jQuery and need to rewrite to pure JS. I find array of elements and need to add onclick event to each of them. But I have a problem with what I need to put inside body function.

jQuery

```
  let Accordion = function (el) {
  this.el = el;
  let dropdownlink = $(".accordion-menu").find('.dropdownlink');

  dropdownlink.on('click', {
      el: this.el
  }, this.dropdown); 
};
```

JavaScript

```
let Accordion = function (el) {
  var dropdownlink = [];
  var outers = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-menu');

        for (var i = 0; i < outers.length; i++) {
            var elements_in_outer = outers[i].querySelectorAll(".dropdownlink");
            elements_in_outer = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements_in_outer);
            dropdownlink = dropdownlink.concat(elements_in_outer);
        }     

 for (var i = 0, len = dropdownlink.length; i < len; i++) {
    dropdownlink[i].onclick = function () {

      // Any ideas?

    }
}};
```

Comment: If there's an element related to each `dropdownlink`, and you need to reference it in the handler, then you should provide an example of the HTML markup. While you could use a closure or something else, it's often simplest to simply select it relative to the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just have far more code than needed.

First, you don't need separate selections to get the `dropdownlink` elements. Just include them in the selector.

Then if you need to reference `el`, you can just do it directly from the handler. And by using an arrow function, you can also use the `this` value present in the `Accordion` constructor.

```
let Accordion = function (el) {
  this.el = el;
  const dropdownlinks = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-menu .dropdownlink');  
  const handler = () => {
    this.dropdown(); // You can access the outer `this` value
    console.log(this.el);
  };

  for (const link of dropdownlinks) {
    link.onclick = handler
  }
};
```